# Escritura y lectura desde archivo en Java

Tags: java

en los métodos que escribo a continuación, estoy intentando guardar objetos(Cliente) en fichero para luego recuperarlos del mismo en imprimirlos por pantalla. Sin embargo, esoy obteniendo como resultado los clientes duplicados. Quizá lo que esté obteniedo duplicado en el caso sean las estructuras HashSet. ¿Alguien ve dónde puede estar el error? Gracias.

Método para Escritura:

```
public static void EscribirFichero(Cliente cl) {
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = null;
    ObjectInputStream objectInput = null;
    HashSet<Cliente> cliHS = new HashSet<Cliente>();            
    try {
        if(FILE_NAME.exists()) {
            objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));
            cliHS = (HashSet<Cliente>) objectInput.readObject();
        }        
        cliHS.add(cl);        
        objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME)); 
        objectOutput.writeObject(cliHS);        
        objectOutput.flush();
        System.out.println("Se ha generado el fichero " + FILE_NAME);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (objectOutput != null) {
            try {
                objectOutput.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Método para lectura:

```
public static void LeerFichero() {
ObjectInputStream objectInput = null;
try {
    objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));
    Object actual = null;
    HashSet<Cliente> cliHS = null;      
    while( ( actual = objectInput.readObject() ) != null ) {
        cliHS = (HashSet<Cliente>) actual;          
        Iterator it = cliHS.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Datos cliente: "+it.next());
        }
    }
    objectInput.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(EOFException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (objectInput != null) {
        try {
            objectInput.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Este era el motivo de mi error:

Un HashSet utiliza el hashCode del objeto que pongo dentro, no el comparador.Si no lo modifico estaré usando la posición de memoria como identificador.Al añadir un cliente se lee primero el HashSet serializado anteriormente, creando objetos cliente en ciertas posiciones de memoria. Si el cliente que añado ya existe, el HashSet no podrá saberlo porque estarán en distintas posiciones de memoria.Es decir son dos objetos distintos aunque contengan exactamente los mismos datos.

Por tanto, era necesario sobreescribir los métodos hashCode y equals de la clase Cliente